# Prove that the ratio of lengths of parallel segments is invariant under affine trasnformations

Tags: geometry, affine-geometry

The complete question is as follows:

> Prove that under an affine transformation the ratio of lengths on
>   parallel line segments is an invariant, but that the ratio of two
>   lengths that are not parallel is not.

Now, the way I was going to prove is the following but I cannot find a way to continue, so maybe I'm missing something.

We have an affine transformation in the form:
$$H = \begin{matrix}
        a & b & x \\
        c & d & y \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}$$
I deleted the previous wrong stuff which I had written previously. Now this should be the correct definition of affine transform and clear the confusion.

Now, let's assume we have two lines $l_1$ and $l_2$ and we pick two points lying on each one of them: $p_1$, $p_2$ on $l_1$ and $p_3$, $p_4$ on $l_2$. We calculate the distance of each pair of points:
$$d_1 = \sqrt{(p_{1x} - p_{2x})^2 + (p_{1y} - p_{2y})^2}$$
This is the distance between the points on the first line, we can then calculate the distance $d_2$ between the points on the second line and then the ratio $d_1 / d_2$.

Then I thought I could apply the transformation $H$ to the points and calculate the new distances and thus the new ratio. Constraining the lines to be parallel should now make the ratios equal and prove the sentence. I'm pretty sure this procedure is indeed correct conceptually but I find it very hard to go on since the resulting expressions of the ratios are not that simple (ratios of square roots). Is there a better/simpler way to achieve the same result?

Comment: What is your _definition_ of an affine transformation?

Comment: I updated the question with the correct definition, I made a mistake earlier and got two concepts confused.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your $H$ is a linear transformation, not an affine one. Write $H(x) = Ax + b$ with $A\in\mathbb R^{2\times 2}, b\in\mathbb R^2$ instead. Using this directly shouldn't be too hard, noting that the things you describe are given by
$$p_1-p_2 = \lambda (p_3-p_4)$$
and you have to show that
$$H(p_1)-H(p_2) = \lambda (H(p_3)-H(p_4))$$

Comment: Why is my $H$ a linear transformation and not an affine?

Comment: @TheCodingMonk You only rotate and dilate (i.e. scale). You can't represent $x\mapsto x+b$ with constant vector $b$ in such a way.

Comment: Oh, right. But I still don't get why you are using the difference between the two points instead of the distance, can you elaborate on that? Thanks

Comment: I thought about it and now I understand.

Comment: You’re operating under a misunderstanding. The OP neglected to explain that he’s working in homogeneous coordinates, i.e., we’re in $\mathbb{RP}^2$, not $\mathbb R^3$. In the latter space, $H$ would indeed represent a linear transformation, but not an affine one, but in the former it represents an affine transformation.