# Does an affine transform really preserve ratios of distances?

Tags: matrices, affine-geometry

Wolfram Alpha says:

> An affine transformation is any transformation that preserves
>   collinearity (i.e., all points lying on a line initially still lie on
>   a line after transformation) and ratios of distances (e.g., the
>   midpoint of a line segment remains the midpoint after transformation).
>   In this sense, affine indicates a special class of projective
>   transformations that do not move any objects from the affine space to
>   the plane at infinity or conversely. An affine transformation is also
>   called an affinity.

But I'm worried that this is inaccurate. If I have a horizontal vector of length 1 and a vertical vector of length 2 and I apply a non-uniform scaling to the space it's very easy to change the ratio to something other than 1:2.

The example they give of a midpoint of a line segment remaining the midpoint after transformation doesn't show the problem. Does the definition really mean "preserves ratios of distances between collinear points"?

Comment: Ratios of segment lengths _of a line_ (and also of parallel lines) are preserved.

Comment: Thanks. If you'd like to make that an answer I'll select it.

Comment: This question also indicates that non-parallel lines would scale differently: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1289536/prove-that-the-ratio-of-lengths-of-parallel-segments-is-invariant-under-affine-t